# Can you express the Feynman propagator as a limit?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration, propagator

At first I thought that the Feynman propagator was the limit of:

$$ G(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 + i \varepsilon} $$

But if you apply the wave equation to this you get:

$$ \Box G(x) = \frac{\varepsilon}{(x^2 + i \varepsilon)^3} $$

So it seems this not the solution to

$$\Box G(x) = \delta_4(x) $$

(Where $\delta_4(x)=\delta(x_0)\delta(x_1)\delta(x_2)\delta(x_4)$). But is the solution to:

$$ \Box G(x) = \varepsilon G(x)^3 $$

(OK so in the limit the RHS is zero). The RHS is like $\delta(x^2)$ instead of $\delta_4(x)$.

So it looks like that my first assumption was wrong. I know if you can get it using the fourier integral:

$$ G_\varepsilon(x) = \int \frac{\exp(i x.k)}{ k^2 + i\varepsilon } dk^4 $$

but I would like to find it as a nice limit not involving integrals or delta functions. I believe the above integral would involve Bessel functions.

It would be OK still if you could show that:

$$\int G(x-y)\Box_y G(y-z)dy^4  = G(x-z) $$ for this function.

**Edit:**

Perhaps the solution is that we define

$$ \lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0} \varepsilon G(x)^3  \equiv \delta_G(x) $$

Since it has all the properties of a delta function. Then the equation would be:

$$ \lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0}\Box G(x) = \delta_G(x) $$

But should then we need to work out what is:

$$ \int G(x-y) \delta_G(y-z) dy^4 = ? $$

to see if it has all the correct properties.

**Edit 2:**

I think it must be that Lorenz invariance is only satisfied in the limit as $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$. So

$$G(x) = \frac{1}{r^2-t^2} + O(\varepsilon,r,t) $$

and

$$\delta_4(x) = \delta(r^2+t^2) $$

So G(x) must be a non-Lorenz invariant function of r,t and $\varepsilon$ which is only Lorenz invariant in the limit.

Although it says in [this book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Pk9yyC239scC&pg=PA870&lpg=PA870&dq=feynman%20propagator%20wave%20equation&source=bl&ots=_aL0Tob_K8&sig=6O_D8z1KwbxXiUGbZ14AQWj8BY4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAWoVChMI1a37mPbuxgIVjCvbCh3riwpz#v=onepage&q=feynman%20propagator%20wave%20equation&f=false) that my first answer was correct!

Maybe is it wrong to use $\delta(r^2+t^2)$ ?

Comment: The propagator (Green function) of the D'Alembertian is a distribution and not a function. So it is not a limit of a function in the usual sense; and I am afraid it is difficult to give a "nicer" expression than the last one you write.

Comment: Not even one that is approximately right?

Comment: Well, you can see any distribution as a suitable limit of smooth functions (in this case functions of rapid decrease, or even compactly supported functions); however the form of the sequence whose limit is $G$ may not be explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that is correct:

$$ G(x) = \frac{1}{x^2+i\varepsilon^2} $$

The equation

$$ \Box G(x) = \delta_4(x) $$

is satisfied since

$$ \lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0} \frac{\varepsilon^2}{(x^2+i\varepsilon^2)^3} = \delta(x^2) $$

Note that $\delta(0) = \frac{1}{\varepsilon^4} $

The issue with $\delta(x^2-x_0^2)$ not being the same as $\delta(x^2+x_0^2)$ is that because these always appear in an integral one can do a **Wick rotation** from one to the other. Hence one is as good as the other! Which, interestingly means a delta function for a single point is equivalent in an integral to a delta function over the entire light cone of a point.

Problem solved.

Also as an aside when normalising G(x) at time $x_0$ one gets a factor of $\varepsilon$:

$$ G(x) = \frac{\varepsilon}{x^2+i\varepsilon^2} \frac{1}{|x_0|^{1/2}} $$

so this behaves like a delta function and proves light always stays on the light cone.